# flutter - using bottomNavigationBar as it is showed at documentation is non-performatic?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

My question is because what it shows at the documentation appears that once the first page is loaded in the app, the entire list of possible pages navigated through the navigationBar will be loaded together.

My impression is that if this is as i think, it will load too much things in the memory as the app starts, causing the app to be slow.

If this works like that, please help me with another way of doing this in a better way, or explain to me why it's not a matter.

the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)
provides the example below:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your impression could be stated as right if that would be how you display certain screens.

But the example you mention is storing different content based on the current index of the bottom navigation bar. It is **not** showing different pages.

Basically, the navigation bar only shows items and keeps track of the currently selected item. There is also a callback `onTap` that you can use to do some action based on the indexed item.

So instead of conditionally rendering a certain Text element based on the index, you can route to a certain page in that callback. When changing pages with routing, the new screen is not loaded before.

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation to learn more about Flutter routing.

Answer (score 0):

use `TabBarView`

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin { // necessary

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
           'Index 0: Home',
           style: optionStyle,
          ),
         Text(
          'Index 1: Business',
          style: optionStyle,
         ),
         Text(
           'Index 2: School',
          style: optionStyle,
         ),
       ],
       physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: (int index) {
          _tabController.animateTo(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }
}
```